# How to fire multiple JavaScript functions at once

Tags: javascript

How do I fire these four functions at exactly the same time;

```
fireThisNow1();
fireThisNow2();
fireThisNow3();
fireThisNow4();
```

Answer (score 6):

You mean asynchronously yes? Try this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    fireThisNow1();
}, 0);

setTimeout(function(){
    fireThisNow2();
}, 0);

setTimeout(function(){
    fireThisNow3();
}, 0);

setTimeout(function(){
    fireThisNow4();
}, 0);
```

Same (if parent object is window):

```
for(var i = 1; i < 5; i++){
    setTimeout(function(){
        window['fireThisNow' + i]();
    }, 0);
}
```

Comment: This will not fire the functions at exactly the same time, but one after each other.

Comment: So fireThisNow2 will fire after fireThisNow1 has started, and before fireThisNow1 has necessarily finished?

Answer (score 3):

When you want to execute multiple functions in parallel (multi-threading), you could use [WebWorkers](http://dev.w3.org/html5/workers/).

Comment: Link to web workers tutorial: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/

Comment: http://caniuse.com/webworkers - Just a reminder that WebWorkers don't work in IE<10.